# OpenGL downgrades on Windows 8/8.1 upgrade

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, gpu, opengl

I have Windows 8.1 Pro N with ATI Radeon 3100 Graphics (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM v1.1) card. I want to play Angry Birds Star Wars II for PC but it keeps saying something about OpenGL 1.4 and 2.0. When I had Windows Vista and Windows 7, the game worked perfectly. I downloaded OpenGL Extensions Viewer and found out that my GPU only supports 1.1 (and 12% of OpenGL 1.2). How can I fix this?

**EDIT:** Here is the OpenGL Extensions viewer main menu:

[image]

and here are the capabilities:

[image]

Comment: try this driver: 64Bit: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy2&os=Windows%208%20-%2064 32Bit: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy2&os=Windows%208%20-%2032

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: what doesn't work? Are you unable to install the driver? OR does the driver still only support OpenGL 1.1?

Comment: It's still 1.1.

Comment: post a picture of OpenGL Extensions Viewer.

Comment: GDI generic looks like a software rendering. Is the AMD GPU correctly detected in device manger?

Comment: Yep. It says ATI Radeon 3100 Graphics (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM v1.1)

Comment: this "Microsoft Corporation - WDDM v1.1" is the inbox driver of Windows which has no OpenGL support, only the 1.1 software rendering. After running the Exe from AMD, you should have a folder C:\AMD or C:\ATI. Use Device Manager to try to install the driver: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/97061-driver-install-device-manager.html

Comment: It says it's up to date, even when trying the new omega driver.

Comment: don't do the automatic scan. Point to the INF file and manually install the driver. The new drivers don't support our old GPU. Here you have to use the legacy driver.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I just did it last night. I did the INF method but the funny part is that I didn't see you're above comment until now. Turns out I can support OpenGL 3.3. THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME!!! Now I can play Angry Birds Star Wars II.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer, so that you can accept it to "close" the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this `Microsoft Corporation - WDDM v1.1` is the inbox driver of Windows which has no OpenGL support, only the 1.1 software rendering. After running the Exe from the AMD legacy driver ([32bit](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy2&os=Windows%208%20-%2032), [64Bit](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy2&os=Windows%208%20-%2064)), you should have a folder C:\AMD or C:\ATI. Use [Device Manager](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/97061-driver-install-device-manager.html) to try to install the driver from the inf. file of the folder C:\AMD or C:\ATI.